# FindBugs null pointer dereference

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, findbugs

I am running findBugs test in my code.

```
if (list != null) {
            TestDTO testDTO;
            for (Object[] object : list) {
                testDTO = new TestDTO();
                testDTO.setId(object[0] != null ? (Integer) object[0] : null);
            }
        }
```

It reports **NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH: Possible null pointer dereference** in the following code.

```
testDTO.setId(object[0] != null ? (Integer) object[0] : null);
```

I couldn't figure out that why it report so ?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the tool to me. Consider editing your question to make it more clear what you are asking for. And add the Java tag, otherwise you won't get much attention

Comment: I am asking that why findBugs reports that issue in the mentioned code.

Comment: I get that. But you want to make that explicit.

Comment: I don't see the point in doing `object[0] != null ? (Integer) object[0] : null` - this could be written as `(Integer) object[0]`. If `testDTO.setId()` expects an `Integer` object all is fine. If however `testDTO.setId()` expects an `int` you might get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: @ThomasKläger: it was expecting Integer, and worked by removing extra code.

Comment: The same error occurred for me with `someVar = (obj == null? null : obj.someMethod());`, which indeed looks like a bug to me. @GhostCat @Abhishek has anyone opened a bug report somewhere?

Comment: Not me ........

Answer (score 0):

Try marking the parameters as @Nullable or @NonNull depending upon the test expectation

check this url

[FIndbug not identifying null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372927/findbug-not-identifying-null-pointer-exception)

Answer (score 0):

> There is a branch of statement that, if executed, guarantees that a null value will be dereferenced, which would generate a NullPointerException when the code is executed. **Of course, the problem might be that the branch or statement is infeasible and that the null pointer exception can't ever be executed**; deciding that is beyond the ability of FindBugs.

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#NP_ALWAYS_NULL_EXCEPTION